# How to simulate these Floquet and Rotation operators for kicked top model?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, matrix-representation

In [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.91.032906) and other papers relating to the kicked top model, it is mentioned that spin coherent states can be expressed as:
$$\left|\theta,\phi\right>=R(\theta,\phi)\left|j,j\right>$$ for given angular momentum *j* and $$R(\theta,\phi)=\exp\left[i\theta(J_x\sin\phi-J_y\cos\phi)\right]$$
The evolution can be described by applying the sequence of Floquet operators $$U=\exp(-ic_1J_z^2)\exp(-ic_2J_y)$$

I want to use this for $j=1$, which means $2$ qubits. The $\left|j,j\right>$ state will be $\left|1,1\right>=\left|11\right>$ state. What are the $4*4$ matrix representations of these operators which can be applied on the two qubit state?

Comment: This question is more related to quantum physics forum